# React native-fetch api call with post request fails

Tags: react-native, fetch

I have created a fecth api call like below

```
var model=new UserAnswer();
  model.category_id=2;
  model.exam_id=this.state.datasourece.exam.id;
  model.questions=this.state.answers;
  fetch(
    API.BASE_URL +
    API.SUBMIT_EXAM,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.props.Login.User.access_token,
      },
      body:JSON.stringify(model)
    },
  )
```

...etc.. but it not working perfectly expected but i have tested the same in postman i got the result.

The JSON.stringify(model) will look like

```
{
"category_id": 2,
"exam_id": 9,
"questions": [
    {
        "question_id": 38,
        "user_answer_option_id": 145
    },
    {
        "question_id": 308,
        "user_answer_option_id": 1142
    },
    {
        "question_id": 309,
        "user_answer_option_id": 1146
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
var model=new UserAnswer();
  model.category_id=2;
  model.exam_id=this.state.datasourece.exam.id;
  model.questions=this.state.answers;
  fetch(
    API.BASE_URL +
    API.SUBMIT_EXAM,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.props.Login.User.access_token,
      },
      body:JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(model))
    },
  )
```

try this.

Thank you.

Comment: if you hosted the API share here.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what is the issue. i have just changed the header accept like below

```
{
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.props.Login.User.access_token,
  },
  body:JSON.stringify(model)
}
```

everything works as expected